# Signalr 2 push fails to single page application

Tags: signalr

This is a single page application with angular js and web api. I implemented signalr on a page that invokes a method server.CheckIfRunning() that checks if a background process is running and pushes a message to client. When I go to that page for the first time, I get the notification successfully. But when I navigate to another page and come back again, the page invokes the server.CheckIfProcessRunning() properly, the server also pushes to the client. But, the client does not receive the notification.

Client side code:

```
  var hub = $.connection.tRAHub;
  hub.client.NotifyAlreadyRunning = function (message) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.status=message;
            });
        };

   $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function () {
            hub.server.checkIfRunning($.connection.hub.id);
   });
```

Server side code:

```
  public class TRAHub : Hub
{
    public void CheckIfRunning(string id)
    {
        var isRunning = CheckIfProcessRunning();//this method checks if the process is running. code not shown

        if (isRunning)
        {
            var client = Clients.Client(id);
            client.NotifyAlreadyRunning(id);
        }
    }
}
```

FYI, the client side code executes whenever I go to that page.
Can anyone please let me know what I have done wrong?

Comment: Can you override OnConnecred and OnDisconnected events on server and client sides to see that client isn't disconnected incorrectly? By the way, you can enable `EnableDetailedErrors` to see if there are any exceptions on the client side.

Comment: Thanks cassandrad. I have tried onconnected and on disconnected methos on server and they seem to work fine. It connects. When i navigate to another view, it doesn't disconnet. But connects agains when i come back to this view. Is this causing troubles? Should i disconnect ehile leaving the view? I'll try to implent the events at client side and will enable enabledetailederrors to see if i can find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out a solution trying different options randomly. On url changing event, while moving to another page, I called the $.connection.hub.stop() method that solved the problem.

Since it calls start() while loading this html page, it was not stopped while moving to another url. And it connects again when i come back to this page. That might have been the problem though it was not documented that calling start() method multiple times messes up though the connection id remains same. Calling the stop method while moving out to another url did tye trick!

Thank you so much guys for your help amd time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use

```
Clients.Caller.NotifyAlreadyRunning(id);
```

See details and other options [here](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#selectingclients).

Comment: DDan, It didn't help. I think the problem is with the events on the angular controller where I'm subscribing to SignalR. The first time it works correctly. When I go to another url, and then come back to the page, it subscribes again, and invokes the CheckIfRunning() method. Then the server also invokes the NotifyAlreadyRunning() correctly. But the client does not recognize that. But, if I refresh the page (F5), it works again. I think when I leave the page and come back again, it needs a refresh that resets the subscription.

Comment: Is your connection id still the same? I suspect that it is not.

Comment: Yes. The connection id is same. Since it is a single page application, it doesn't get refreshed. And the connection id remains same. When I hit F5, it connects with a new id.

Comment: They might have not think of single page applications when they implemented SignalR for JS. One simple way would be to reconnect once you are back at the page again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to abstract the signalr stuff in a service. As a result of that, you can handle it once at startup and forward the events from server to the active controller.
You can implement something like an observer pattern. Subscribe events from your signalr services at creation of controller an unsubscribe at deconstruction.

There is also a possible solution which an existing angularjs signalR module:
https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub